# Redis: get value from sorted sets as rpop in list

Tags: redis

I want to store data as key value in Redis. Using sorted sets for that, as list do not allow to store data in key value format. So using sorted sets.

But I want data to be poped as it works in redis list rpop.

ZREM of redis needs member to get the score, plus its a sorted list so can i store in first come method?

Or should i change the data structure I am using?

Comment: I think you need to mix datatypes in redis to achieve this. Anyways have posted one possible solution with sorted set

Comment: new to stackoverflow, did not know i can accept the answer. Thanks for letting me know this.

Comment: @Tamil i did not tried it so far, once i will, will comment surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution but you should decide on its efficiency ;)

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE key +inf -inf LIMIT 0 1
```

One possible thing you can do is using redis `lists` and store your data as

```
key[FS]value
```

Ex: name:xxx

So, once you pop your data out you can manually split them in client end

Comment: It doesn't remove a member from set. We can remove it manually with zrem but it not gonna work in high concurrency because parallel requests will obtain same member with zrevrangebyscore.

Comment: I have the same requirement, any solution you got  Bogdan?